# Define dynamic environment path variables for different system configuration

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not sure if this is a valid question, but I'm stuck doing this.
I've a python script which does some operation on my local system
Users/12345/Desktop/Sample/one.py

I want the same to be run on remote server whose path is 
Server/Users/23552/Dir/ASR/Desktop/Sample/one.py

I know how to do this in PHP using define path APP_HOME sort of I'm baffled in Python
Can someone pl help me?

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking. Can you describe the use case *and the problem you're encountering* in more detail?

Comment: My python script do some operation on my local system, obv the dir path will be different, i want the same to be run on other's system also which will throw path error. Is there a way we can define dir path or some confi for others too

Comment: Basically I need different configuration path for different systems

Comment: use command-line arguments to pass the relevant path to the script...

Comment: Can you let me know how ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the relative path, I guess relative path should solve your issue.